# color of tick marks

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i change the color of the tick marks from gray to black like the axis color?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style = {pin edge={Latex-,thin,black}}]
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
                     grid = major,
         inner axis line style={=>},
                 width=10cm,height=5cm,
                     ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
                     xmin=-5,xmax=5,
                     axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4},
                     major tick style = thick,
                     ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
                     every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$x$},
                 ylabel={$f(x)$}]
                    \addplot[red,only marks] coordinates {(-4,0.2)(-2,0.5)(-1,0.8)(2,0.9)(3,1)};
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-5:-4] {0} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-4:-2] {0.2} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-2:-1] {0.5} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-1:2] {0.8} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=2:3] {0.9} ;
 \addplot[red,very thick,domain=3:5] {1} ;
\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: I posted the solution here please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70157475/9965151

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tick style can be globally changed using `pgfplotsset`:

```
\pgfplotsset{tick style={black}}
```

See section 4.15 of the documentation for more tick options.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go!

The color of the tick marks is quite simple, just adjust the `major tick style` accordingly. I used `major tick style = {thick, black}`.

To make the tick labels above the plot (that you [forgot to mention](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412942/plotted-function-overlaid-by-the-gridlines/412945?noredirect=1#comment1031041_412945) in your question) but keeping the axis grid below it is trickier.

I found something similar [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316259/how-to-color-tick-label-background-when-curve-overlaps-it/316277). You have to configure the order in which `pgfplots` draws each layer.

To do that you use this:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={set layers=tick labels on top},
    layers/tick labels on top/.define layer set=
        {axis background,
         axis grid,
         axis lines,
         main,
         axis tick labels,
         axis ticks,
         axis descriptions,
         axis foreground}
       {/pgfplots/layers/standard}
}
```

The order in which the layers appear in the `define layer set` is the order that pfgplots will draw them. See that first comes the `axis grid`, then the actual plot (`main`), then the `axis tick labels` and `axis ticks`.

The result is black tick marks and tick labels above the plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}


\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={set layers=tick labels on top},
    layers/tick labels on top/.define layer set=
        {axis background,
         axis grid,
         axis lines,
         main,
         axis tick labels,
         axis ticks,
         axis descriptions,
         axis foreground}
       {/pgfplots/layers/standard}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin/.style = {pin edge={Latex-,thin,black}},small     dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}]
\begin{axis}[standard,scale only axis,
         axis x line=middle,
         axis y line=middle,
                     grid = major,
         inner axis line style={=>},
                 width=10cm,height=5cm,
                     ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
                     xmin=-5,xmax=5,
                     axis line style = thick,
                     xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4},
                     major tick style = {thick, black},
                     ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
                    % axis on top,% <- HERE
                 every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
         every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north)},above=0.5mm},
                 xlabel={$x$},
                 ylabel={$f(x)$},
 %               axis on top <- AND HERE
                 ]
                    \addplot[red,only marks] coordinates {(-4,0.2)(-2,0.5)(-1,0.8)(2,0.9)(3,1)};
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-5:-4] {0} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-4:-2] {0.2} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-2:-1] {0.5} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=-1:2] {0.8} ;
\addplot[red,very thick,domain=2:3] {0.9} ;
 \addplot[red,very thick,domain=3:5] {1} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```